# How to have a page support to typing keyboard to launch a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

This [link](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/master?filepath=binder/Index.ipynb) would launch a jupyter notebook.

[image]

When the page is loaded,

typing <kbd>h</kbd>, would launch a modal ("Keyboard shortcuts")

[image]

typing <kbd>f</kbd>, would launch another modal "Find and Replace"

[image]

How to have a page support to typing keyboard to launch a modal?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58023877/10449636) gives some inspiration inside modal.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_keypress) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress) give examples about a single element, although I am asking an approach to listen keypress event on whole page

## question

Here is my code which is trying to listen any keypress

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        i = 0;
        $(document).querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            $("span").text(i += 1);
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="mydiv" tabindex="0">
        <p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How to make this code work?

Comment: short answer: by programming it. You listen to keyboard events and then react accordingly. There is no "out of the box" feature to do this.

Comment: @cloned plz check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58023877/10449636)

Comment: The answer is still the same: You can't just add a bunch of stuff to your HTML, you will have to code the functionality you need.

Comment: @cloned Did you really run the 2 snippets in that post? snippet_1 does not support the keyboard feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wiring the event incorrectly. With jQuery, use `on()` to wire the event and provide the selector for your target element in the second argument:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    i = 0;
    $(document).on('keyup', '#mydiv', function(e) {
      $("span").text(i += 1);
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="mydiv" tabindex="0">
    <p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Of course, remember to click inside the element before you start typing. Now, if you want to know what key was pressed, you can use `e.key`. That's good if you want to get the characters, but if you want to implement shortcuts, it's better to use `e.keyCode`:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on('keyup', '#mydiv', function(e) {
      $("span").text(e.key + " (" + e.keyCode + ")");
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="mydiv" tabindex="0">
    <p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You code works only for a line rather than the whole page. Would you please help take a look at [this](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/master?filepath=binder/Index.ipynb), which responses keyboard on whole page.

Comment: It works for an element, not a line. It just so happened that your element contains one line, but you can make it bigger if you like. If you want it to work on the entire page, then simply remove the element selector `"#mydiv"` in the second argument like this `$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please take a look at this [line](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ipython/ipython-in-depth/master?filepath=binder/Index.ipynb)? I searched 'keyup', 'keydown' and 'keypress', none of them is found in jupyter notebook. What is jupyter notebook using to response on whole page?

Comment: They use `keypress`.

Comment: Is the keyword "keypress", with which I searched and got nothing.

Comment: You need to know where to search. JavaScript code is not always on same page, most of it is in linked files. You will need to download all of them and then do a global search in the entire folder and subfolders. Anyway, this is off-topic. StackOverflow is a questions/answers platform, not a "search in files" assistance tool.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this

```
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            if (event.defaultPrevented) {
                return;
            }

            var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
            console.log(key); // which "key" is the key you clicked on
            // Then you should test which key is clicked so you can do whatever you want like so
            if(key == 'Esc'){
              //Do the magic

            }
        });
```