# Is it possible to have a CodeMirror-lines support copy-paste-hyperlink for markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown, codemirror

A jupyter notebook cell is a [CodeMirror-lines](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) (Please correct me if needed). Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58026260/10449636) if you are not familiar with jupyter notebook.

Here is the code of a blank markdown cell.

```
<div class="cell text_cell unrendered unselected" tabindex="2">
    <div class="prompt input_prompt"></div>
    <div class="inner_cell">
        <div class="ctb_hideshow">
            <div class="celltoolbar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_area" aria-label="Edit Markup Text here">
            <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-default CodeMirror-wrap">
                <div
                    style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 5.59999px; left: 5.6px;">
                    <textarea autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0"
                        style="position: absolute; bottom: -1em; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="CodeMirror-vscrollbar" cm-not-content="true">
                    <div style="min-width: 1px; height: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="CodeMirror-hscrollbar" cm-not-content="true">
                    <div style="height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
                <div class="CodeMirror-gutter-filler" cm-not-content="true"></div>
                <div class="CodeMirror-scroll" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="CodeMirror-sizer"
                        style="margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: -12px; border-right-width: 18px; min-height: 28px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                        <div style="position: relative; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="CodeMirror-lines" role="presentation">
                                <div role="presentation" style="position: relative; outline: none;">
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-measure"></div>
                                    <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"></div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-cursors">
                                        <div class="CodeMirror-cursor" style="left: 5.6px; top: 0px; height: 16.8px;">
                                            &nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="CodeMirror-code" role="presentation">
                                        <pre class=" CodeMirror-line "
                                            role="presentation"><span role="presentation" style="padding-right: 0.1px;"><span cm-text="">​</span></span></pre>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        style="position: absolute; height: 18px; width: 1px; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; top: 28px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="CodeMirror-gutters" style="display: none; height: 46px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text_cell_render rendered_html" tabindex="-1">
            <p>Type <em>Markdown</em> and LaTeX: <span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit;"><span
                        class="MJXp-math" id="MJXp-Span-1"><span class="MJXp-msubsup" id="MJXp-Span-2"><span
                                class="MJXp-mi MJXp-italic" id="MJXp-Span-3" style="margin-right: 0.05em;">α</span><span
                                class="MJXp-mn MJXp-script" id="MJXp-Span-4"
                                style="vertical-align: 0.5em;">2</span></span></span></span>
                <script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1">\alpha^2</script>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Editing a markdown in VS Code, copy a URL and paste on a text would make the text a markdown link/hyperlink.

Is it possible to implement this feature to a CodeMirror-lines?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant: When a user pastes a link, make it a clickable hyperlink within the CodeMirror editor?

On initialization disable paste events with codemirror's `beforeChange` function. When the user pastes inside the `.CodeMirror`, check if the clipboard content starts with either `http://` or `https://`, if so then we create a codemirror widget hyperlink, else we just insert the clipboard content found.

The only issue I have found with this is that you cannot paste a link one after another...

Well, the user who asked this is no more. There is another "issue" that you cannot get that line's value using `editor.getValue()`. Not sure if there is even a way to insert a clickable element into the editor and capture it with the editor's value.

**Note:** StackOverflow blocks links in the snippet so you won't be able to see it in action here, but you can view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/GRKbWoR).

```js
$(function() {

  var editorOptions = {
    autoRefresh: true,
    firstLineNumber: 1,
    lineNumbers: true,
    smartIndent: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    indentWithTabs: true,
    refresh: true,
    mode: 'javascript'
  };

  // initialization
  $('.content').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(self.find(".editor")[0], editorOptions);
    self[0].editor = editor;
    editor.save();

    // disable paste events
    editor.on("beforeChange", function(_, change) {
      if (change.origin == "paste") change.cancel()
    });
  });

  $(document).on('paste', '.CodeMirror', function(e) {
    // prevent default paste event
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = $(this).closest('.content');
    var editor = content[0].editor;
    navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {
      if (text.match(/^(https?:\/\/).*/g)) {
        // if the clipboard content begins with 'http://' or 'https://', create a codemirror widget
        var newText = text;
        var el = $('<a class="markdown-link" href="' + newText + '" target="_blank">' + newText + '</a>')[0];
        var line = editor.getCursor().line;
        var ch = editor.getCursor().ch;
        var isEmptyLine = editor.getLine(line).trim() === "";
        if (isEmptyLine) {
          // if line is empty we insert the widget here
          editor.replaceRange(' ', {line});
        } else if (ch === 0) {
          // if character position is zero, don't do anything
          editor.replaceRange(' ' + "\n", pos);
        } else {
          // if line has content, insert widget on new line
          editor.replaceRange("\n" + ' ', {line});
          line++;
        }
        var widget = editor.markText({line, ch: 0}, {line, ch: 1}, {
          replacedWith: el
        });
        editor.focus();
      } else {
        // else just insert the clipboard content.
        // use insertText rather than insertHTML when pasting html elements into codemirror editor.
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.CodeMirror {
  height: fit-content !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.CodeMirror-line {
  line-height: 1.5 !important;
}

.CodeMirror-vscrollbar,
.CodeMirror-hscrollbar {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.markdown-link {
  background: #e8f0fe;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.40.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.48.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.35.0/codemirror.css" />
<div class="content">
  try inserting text that begins with "http://" or "https://"
  <textarea class="editor" style="display: none;">var str = "Hello,World!";
console.log("hello, there!"); 
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});</textarea>
</div>
```